# Android - Set the Source of an ImageView inside a custom listView adapter from the getView function does not work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

Apologies for the long title.

I am building an Android application where an activity contains a custom listView. In the layout of my custom listView, I have an image view and three textViews. I am fetching the data from the database and I have no issues with the row data as they're accurate. However, I have issues with displaying the ImageViews.

What I do to populate the imageView is that I get the imagePath stored from the database, parse that URL (local server only), then set the ImageViews Bitmap with that.

During the `getView` function of my customListView class, I create a thread that processes the url from the database and then I parse that, then set that as the ImageView's bitmap.

Here is my `getView` function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nominees_list_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.firstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomineesListFirstName);
        holder.middleName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomineesListMiddleName);
        holder.lastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomineesListLastName);
        holder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomineesListCandidatePhoto);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.firstName.setText(listData.get(position).getFirst_name());
    holder.middleName.setText(listData.get(position).getMiddle_name());
    holder.lastName.setText(listData.get(position).getLast_name());

    new setDisplayPhoto().execute(listData.get(position).getPicture_path());

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see, I am initializing the view components then setting their values based on the listData taken from the database. The data displayed are all correct. Then, what I do for the imageView is that I create an AsyncTask and feed the data there.

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
private class setDisplayPhoto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String toastMessage = "Downloading nominees photo finished.";

    Bitmap mIcon_val;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d("","doInBackGround Started");

        String photo_url_str  = "http://192.168.0.10:8888/server/path/here/"
                + params[0];

        try {
            Log.d("","photo_url_str = " + photo_url_str);
            newurl = new URL(photo_url_str);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());

            holder.photo.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "Executed!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

However, the photos do not appear, and if they do, sometimes the photos are jumbled up.

Can someone help me with how to properly set the image source of an imageView during the getView function of the customListView Adapter when the source is taken from a local server? Thank you for any help.

Comment: network operation always runs in a secondary thread....So if you give a url path and try to download it will download it in some other thread, So it is better have your own asynctask try downloading image have a call back to your adapter after downloading it . depending on the visibility of the position display the image .

Comment: I'm trying to do away with actually downloading the file as I want the system to be flexible by being able to get the files from a server without having to download it.

Comment: In your case maintaining the position of listitems is very important... cause listview is based on the recycling concept.. So if you pass the imageview object no matter which position is visible your thread will try to set the image to that imageview

Comment: you are downloading it,, it not possible to display server image without downloading it.. its just that you are not saving it in the secondary storage .. it will be in your primary memory ..

Comment: And i wound not recommend this kind of image downloading cause in android keeping so many images in primary memory either end up causing out of memory exception or everytime when the user scrolls you end up downloading many copies of same image ..

Comment: So I'd have to store the image somewhere in the device memory locally?

Comment: correct .. once you download and store it . and you can delete it once the user goes out of that screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason it's not working it's because dealing with image download, cache and view recycling is way way more complex than what your code is handling.

I can point it out a few things I can see it's wrong from your code, but for sure there's more:

- there's no RAM cache, that means the moment the user scrolls a view out if view and then back into view, the image will be downloaded again from the server.
- there's no disk cache, that means that if the user scrolls too far in a list, or if he/she leaves the app for a few minutes to later come back, the image will be downloaded again from the server
- on this line `holder.photo.setImageBitmap` you're trying to change a `View` in a background thread.
- AsyncTask (starting on some API) is a mono-thread class, meaning all your downloads will be queue in happen one after the other, so probably the user will be staring at a blank screen for a while before seeing anything.
- you're not canceling the task, so during recycling, the call `setImageBitmap` might be happening on the wrong item.

replace the line:

```
new setDisplayPhoto().execute(listData.get(position).getPicture_path());
```

with:

```
Picasso.with(convertView.getContext())
    .load("http://192.168.0.10:8888/server/path/here/" +
                       listData.get(position).getPicture_path())
    .into(holder.photo);
```

for that to work you'll need one extra libary that you can add by adding the following line on your manifest:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

for more info on the library check this: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Would I have to do this in an AsyncTask?

Comment: No! Directly replace the code inside `getView` and you can throw away the AsyncTask code. the Picasso library deals with all the issues regarding threading.

Comment: oh my good Lord that sounds really really really really good. I'll check asap and give feedback asap.

Comment: YOU, KIND SIR, ARE A LIFESAVER. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Life saver are those guys at square that created the library. I'm just happy to spread the word

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.jojo.gridview;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GirdViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> ar;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GirdViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> ar, Activity con)
    {
        activity = con;
        this.ar=ar;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ar.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView = arg1;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (arg1 == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_view, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String rowData[] = this.ar.get(position).split("\\|");
        viewHolder.textView.setText(rowData[0] );
        setImageView(viewHolder.imageView, rowData[1] );
        return rowView;
    }

    private void setImageView(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        class ImageDownloadHelper extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                URL url;
                String _url = params[0];
                Log.e("url",_url );

                BufferedOutputStream out;
                InputStream in;
                BufferedInputStream buf;

                try {
                    url = new URL(_url);
                    in = url.openStream();
                    buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);

                    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }
                    if (buf != null) {
                        buf.close();
                    }
                    return bMap;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        ImageDownloadHelper downloadHelper = new ImageDownloadHelper();
        downloadHelper.execute(url);
        try {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadHelper.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```