# Ways to Minimize High RAM Usage

Tags: android, arrays, memory, bitmap

I am developing an app currently that has a very high memory footprint, and is extremely content-oriented. I have up to hundreds of "submissions", each with the possibility of having a small thumbnail or large bitmap image, along with an array list of potentially 40-50 strings of data, and all of this is inside of one activity, of which there may be multiple. It's currently using upwards of 150MB of RAM, and lots of users are complaining of crashes due to out of memory. It also becomes sluggish after a while of use, which I am trying to improve.

I am currently using 1/8 of available ram for my LruCache of images, and in my fragment for each submission I load a list of strings which goes into an array per-submission. If I try to retrieve the image and one doesn't exist, I load it up a new one and put it back in the cache, which is working OK, but I am still using a ton of memory. The cache is static, shared across all my activities, so that isn't the issue. Would having an array of strings with many child views inside a fragment be adding to my memory issue?

What steps can I take to minimize my ram usage and speed my app up?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use a heap profiler and make sure that what I think is using the RAM really is-  that you have no leaks and no uncontrolled buildup of objects.

Comment: I suggest you checking this answer I gave earlier today and replace all this bitmap management code you're doing yourself by a library that is proved to work very well http://stackoverflow.com/a/29491993/906362

Comment: Im currently using the Ion library, any improvements Picasso has over Ion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What Gabe says, is something you should do, but that apart, let me give you a approach you can take to this.

Firstly, those 40-50 strings aren't per se causing your RAM issue (unless there is a memory leak). The bitmaps are the culprit.

I would strongly recommend using a library like Volley to upload data, as that would improve memory management in itself. Next, go through the code and figure out if you are keeping your Bitmap/Drawable variables in scope longer than they are needed. If yes, destroy them.

Also, if multiple images are to be uploaded, queue them. Save the queued images in your cache or app data, and when the turn comes, retrieve them, upload them, and clear the intermediate saved one from it's location.

Comment: I am currently using Ion to load my image data, would using volley have any immediate improvements over Ion? Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: Do check out Frescolib.org 
Facebook uses to load images in their own Facebook app, and per my experience, is the best image loading library.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 10, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD on my laptop and it use to consume consistently more than 50% memory even if it is on idle state.
I had to find and workout on the problem for a while but I came to know some good solutions that really helped.

Do's:

- you can disable xbox gamebar whenever you are not playing games. In task manager you can see it's process name is "Service Host: Game-DVR", can be ended there too. This process particularly consumes lots of memory.
- you can change your antivirus being windows defender by default to some other software, it consumes lesser memory that way. Disabling defender is also an option but not a great idea. still remember to keep your firewall always on to avoid any unwanted problems.
- you can disable startup processes which you do not require.
- remember to close any unnecessary tabs in browser. Browser is a big consumer of RAM.
- You can shut-down service host: sysmain process, but I'm not sure if it could harm performance. To me, I found no harm with that, but only problem is it pops up again in few minutes.

Don'ts:

- never change your paging settings or anything like that which may be some solution on the internet. That would feel as a solution but costs extra CPU cycles and disk usage which will definitely countereffect your purpose.